# Windows 10 Xbox App unable to record with Game DVR, it saids pc can't record clips

Tags: windows-10, xbox-game-dvr

The Windows 10 Xbox App is unable to record game play with the Game DVR feature. It says  **pc can't record clips** in the settings.

I have a NVIDIA GTX 780, with all recent drivers. I uninstalled and reinstalled the app, used CCleaner and Windows Defender to check registry/malwares, restarted the Broadcast GameDVR service, and installed all updates from Windows Update. Everything is up to date. I even tested with an AMD R9 280X graphic card, and same issue. Nothing works.

when you click learn more, it goes to this link https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=534010 , is basically a link to Bing search engine with some predifned query, and the first result tells you about the minimum graphics card you need, and im sure i have a compatible one

i also checked this

https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-windows/system-requirements/pc-hardware-requirements-for-game-dvr

https://support.xbox.com/en-US/xbox-on-windows/social/troubleshoot-game-dvr-windows-10

Is there any solution for this?

[image: pc can't record clips message]

[image: record button disabled]

Comment: What does the "learn more" indicate is the reasons you cannot record clips.  I have the same card, I can record clips, so it isn't your GPU hardware that's the reason

Comment: @Ramhound when you click learn more, it goest this link https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=534010 , that basically is a link to Bing with some search, the first result just tells you about the minimum graphics card you need, and im sure i have a compatible one

Comment: Update your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution by "accident", i was about to upgrade my Windows 10 to Anniversary update, and i had a issue that it can´t update my windows because it was installed in a USB Device , but it wasn´t , it is on a SSD Drive, anyways , searching in internet i found the solution to that problem was

1. From the Desktop press "Win" + R
2. type **regedit**
3. Go to **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control**
4. Change the entry **PortableOperatingSystem** from **1** to **0**
5. Save and Restart

I did that, and the GameDVR record button start to works , all this without the update yet , this solution was to fix the issue with the Win10 Anniversary update , but seems that Windows GameDVR doesn´t record if the OS is set as PortableOperativeSystem

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did not work for me. Keep in mind my problem is that processor I have is out of date for dvr software, the solution was:

1. download file *GameDVR_Config.exe* from https://github.com/FunkyFr3sh/GameDVR_Config/releases and run as administrator
2. Enable these properties: 
   **Enable Game DVR (WIN+G)**;
   **Enable audio capture**;
   **Forece software MFT(16FPS + VBR) (must to work)**;
   **Disable cursor blending (must to work)**;
   **Record game in the background**;

[image: image how it should look]

3. And without closing this window press WIN+G and start recording

Update:
After some time of using it I saw that service BcastDVRUserService_31298 will automatically starts and doing some unnecessary background job even if not recording, so make sure set this service to manual startup